# Chrome logs me out of everything when I exit--tried cookie-related stuff already

Tags: session, google-chrome, cookies, login, logout

I've been using Chrome very successfully for a long time. It has always kept me logged in to all my sites even after exiting the app. Recently it started logging me out of everything when I exit Chrome. I've fooled around with all the various advanced cookie settings, and I've cycled through the options hoping that Chrome just needed a wakeup call or a reset or something. I've also deleted all the cookies in case a corrupted one is confusing Chrome.

Nothing works! I see cookies when I log in, but they all go away when I exit Chrome. I've searched all over the place and seen only the standard answers relating to resetting cookies, local data, sessions, that sort of thing.

Any Chrome gurus out there, please send a telepathic message to my browser asking it to resume its previous excellent behavior. Alternatively, you could suggest other possible solutions.